# Why is this form navigating me to an error page?

Tags: php, forms

I have this code below where what should happen is that if the `$sessionMinus` (which is a number) is not the same as `($_SESSION['initial_count'])`, then  the form submits to itself which I want to happen BUT if `$sessionMinus`  equals the same number as `($_SESSION['initial_count'])` then I want the form to submit to the create_session2.php.

But the problem is that if I click on the submit button, no matter what happens, it keeps taking me to an error page, no matter if the numbers match or not. Why is this happening? (This happens if I use both == and === signs).

Below is code:

```
<?php
session_start();

    if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){

        $action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? "create_session2.php" : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    }

?>


<body>    
        <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >

...

</body>
```

Solution is Below:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = 'create_session2.php'; 

}else if($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

}

?>

<body>

            <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >



...
</body>
```

Comment: What page is it directing you to?  Is the behavior expected if those variables arn't equal.

Comment: When you say error page - what kind? Is it an Error 500, or what?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with form destination or form tag (I know I did not include </form> in question), there is something definetly wrong with the code I provided but I don't know why?

Comment: What's being sent to your browser? What does the browser think the `action` of the form is?

Comment: Right guys, something I have just found out, in a previous page I say how many sessions I want. If I say I want 1 session, then on the current page it is session 1 of 1 and if you submit form, it works fine (it directs me to create_session2.php). But if I said I want 2 sessions, then for first session which is session 1 of 2, then if I submit form then it takes to me to my server's error page errorpages/error404.htm and not back to its own page (PHP_SELF). These numbers are the $sessionMinus and $_SESSION['initial_count']

Comment: So what happens when $sessionMinus != $_SESSION['inital_count']? What does $action get set to? What reaches the browser in the `action` attribute?

Comment: If you say it like that then nothing, I though the way I did it I thought I stated if numbers match,  then post to create_session2.php or (using :) navigate back to itself using (PHP_SELF)

Comment: Yes: if the numbers match, $action gets set. What happens when the numbers don't match? Is it set? What is in the `action` attribute when the numbers don't match? (How many times do I have to ask for that information?)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have just stated that nothing happens if nothing matches, I am trying to sort this out if numbers don't match but it is giving me a stupid unexpected ; error which I am trying to solve :)

Comment: Use a sheet of paper to cover up your code, and uncover it a line at a time so you can examine each line in turn. See what happens if $sessionMinus != $SESSION['initial_count']. And do a View Source in the browser and see what the `action` attribute is set to, since that's what's sending it to the error page.

Comment: Figured it out, solution was what AndrewLeach mentioned if I change code to solution I have mentioned above, then it works. This way it states what happens if there is or isn't a match

Comment: Great :-) Sorry: I wasn't going to give you the answer since you tagged it [tag:homework]. You could probably have taken out the `if` entirely and just had the `$action = (...)` statement since that does the test and assigns a value. I believe you can answer your own question, which will flag it answered in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things this could be:

1. Check your php_error.log file for more debug information, it will usually have some info about what is causing the error.
2. It looks like your PHP statements and your HTML aren't separated properly (assuming these lines of code are one right after another). You need a `?>` tag after the `if` block but before the `<form>` tag. So your code would be:

   ```
   <?php /* <- this should be above this line already in your code */

   if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) {
       $action = ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? "create_session2.php" : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   }
   /* you need to add the tag below */
   ?>
   <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
   ```
3. Where you assign the `$action` variable, consider wrapping the expression in parentheses, like this:

   ```
   $action = (($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? "create_session2.php" : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   ```

and also changing `PHP_SELF` to `REQUEST_URI` (as `PHP_SELF` gives the file path relative to the document root, not the full path including document root), and adding the full path to the `create_session2.php` file:

```
    $action = (($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/create_session2.php" : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

You shouldn't have to add the `SERVER_NAME` bit, but I always prefer absolute paths in my links.

If you can provide any more source code, it would be very helpful.

-T

Comment: Hi, I just copied and post code in, I will update code but ?> tags and etc are in right places before you mentioned them

Comment: Hi, tried the parenthesis theory you have stated but still no luck, do I have to use REQUEST_URI?

Comment: No, you shouldn't **have** to use it. Can you check the source code of the generated page and see what the action of the form is?

Comment: I think AndrewLeach is right, What I think I have done is said if there is a match, then post form to create_session2.php but I never stated that if there isn't a match, then post form to itself (PHP_SELF). This is what I am trying to figure out but I am getting a stupid error

Comment: Figured it out, solution was what AndrewLeach mentioned if I change code to solution I have mentioned above, then it works